# Missing features of Ada record

Tags: c++, initialization, constants, record, ada

[Consider following C++ code:](http://ideone.com/GZqvzi)

```C++
class Person
{
public:
    const std::string Name;
    int Weight = 0;
    Person(std::string AssignName) : Name(AssignName)
    {}
};

void Dinner(Person & ModifyPerson)
{
    ModifyPerson.Weight += 2;
}
```

Name is constant and it is first initialized when a Person is created.
Weight is modifiable.

```C++
Person Person0("Conny");
Dinner(Person0);
```

Lets try this in Ada:

```Ada
type Person is record
    Name : constant String;
    Weight : Integer := 0;
end record;

Person0 : Person := Person'(Name => "Abby");
```

The *Person*'s name should always be "Abby" because its constant and the *Weight* should be modifiable and 0 as defualt.

Does not work because Ada record does not allow following:

- Constant field
- Unspecified range for field type
- Limiting the initialization list i.e. only assign *Name* and have *Weight* = 0 as default.

How can I do the C++ code in Ada code?

In C++ I can extend the *Person* by deriving it.
In Ada we use tagged record for that.
But tagged record does also not work.

How can I do the C++ code in Ada code with extendable capabilities of *Person*?

Comment: You’ve used `std::string` which avoids the need to specify a range. The Ada equivalent would be an `Unbounded_String`. I don’t know C++ well at all, but I suspect you’d have had problems if you’d declared `Name : char[];`.

Answer (score 8):

In Ada you first decide what a `Person` can and cannot do, and design the interface. The implementation comes later.

As far as I can see from your class, you want a Person to:

1. have an immutable name (marriage may be a problem, but never mind)
2. Have a mutable weight, initialised to 0
3. have the ability to gain or lose weight.
4. From the discussion, be extensible (subclassable)

Now an Ada record is like a Struct, but we want a bit more than that, and the usual way to wrap a datatype and its operations together is a `Package`. (This also has some commonality with a C++ namespace, it also keeps the main namespace uncluttered)

```
Package Person_Pack is
  -- tagged for extensibility and other goodies
  type Person (Name_Length : Natural) is tagged private;
  function Name (P:Person) return String;
  function Weight (P:Person) return Natural;
  procedure Gain_Weight (P: in out Person; Increment : Integer);
  -- Explicit constructor, like "object factory" pattern
  function Birth(Name : String) return Person;
private
  -- none of your business yet...
end Person_Pack;
```

And that's the interface (save it as "person_pack.ads"). There is a getter method but no setter method for Name, we have guaranteed `Person.Name`'s constancy.

The private part contains the details of the type declaration, so that client code can allocate space for a `Person` and basically no other reason. So, no fiddling with record fields other than by the public interface... I don't think I need to spell out why that's a good thing? So the private part could look like

```
private
  type Person (Name_Length : Natural) is tagged record
    Name   : String(1 .. Name_Length);
    Weight : Integer := 0;
  end record;
end Person_Pack;
```

This is a discriminated record so we can store the Name directly in the record rather than using Ada.Containers (the nearest equivalent to STL) or even Unbounded_String. That's an implementation detail, as it's restricted to the private part, if we change it later without changing the interface, and recompile, client code still works.

Implementation is in the package body, "person_pack.adb".

```
Package Body Person_Pack is
  function Name (P:Person) return String is
  begin
    return P.Name;
  end Name;

  function Weight (P:Person) return Natural is
  begin
    return P.Weight;
  end Weight;

  procedure Gain_Weight (P: in out Person; Increment : Integer) is
  begin
    P.Weight := P.Weight + Increment;
  end Gain_Weight;

  function Birth(Name : String) return Person is
    baby : Person(Name'Length);
  begin
    baby.Name := Name;
    baby.Weight := 0;
    return baby;
  end Birth;

end Person_Pack;
```

Usage (save as main.adb):

```
with Person_Pack; use Person_Pack;

procedure Main is

  -- type extension : refactor this into another package...
  type Employee is new Person with
    record
      Salary : Integer;
    end record;

  function Birth(Name : String) return Employee is
    baby : Person(Name'Length) := Birth(Name);
  begin
    return (baby with Salary => 0);
  end Birth;

  Abby : Person := Birth("Abigail");
  John : Employee := Birth("John");

  procedure Dinner (Gourmand : in out Person) is
  begin
    Gourmand.Gain_Weight(2);
  end Dinner;

begin
  Dinner(Abby);
end Main;
```

Compile with:

```
gcc -c -gnat2012 main.adb
gcc -c -gnat2012 person_pack.adb
gnatbind -x main.ali; gnatlink main.ali
```

Comment: Procedure `Dinner` should fail to compile, since `Gourmand` is only an `in` parameter.

Comment: Seems like Person should be declared with an unknown discriminant in the public part (given its definition in private). This will also force users to call Birth to create new users, and thus ensures that the Name is properly initialized.

Answer (score 5):

Public data members are frowned upon in *any* object-oriented language.  So even in C++, I would expect people with a solid design background to tell you to put `Name` and `Weight` in the `private:` section, and add getter and setter methods to retrieve and set the fields.  Of course you wouldn't have a setter for `Name` since it's unchangeable.

Same thing in Ada.  Make the `record` private:

```
    type Person is private;  --or
    type Person is tagged private;

    function Make_Person (Name : String; Weight : Integer := 0) return Person;

    function Get_Name (X : Person) return String;

    function Get_Weight (X : Person) return Integer;
    procedure Set_Weight (X : in out Person; Weight : Integer);

private

    type Person is record --or
    type Person is tagged record 
        Name : Ada.Strings.Unbounded.Unbounded_String;
        Weight : Integer;
    end record;
```

`Unbounded_String` is the usual way to deal with string variables or record fields whose length can change dynamically.  See [RM A.4.5](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rm/html/RM-A-4-5.html) for information on how to use this package, and how to convert between `Unbounded_String` and `String` types.  Those conversions would appear only in the body of the package that defines `Person`; a client package that uses the `Person` would not have to worry about it.

If you make `Person` a `tagged record`, you can still use the "dot" notation to access the functions:

```
P : Person;

...

Name : String := P.Get_Name;       -- calls the getter function
Weight : Integer := P.Get_Weight;  -- calls the getter function

P.Set_Weight (P.Get_Weight + 2);
```

I cannot respond to your statement that "tagged record does also not work", because you haven't provided any specifics.